# How to disable Today and future dates in angular by using ngx-bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: angular

[image]I am new to Angular.
Can anyone help with this?

To disable today and future dates I used this code?

```
<input class="form-control"
           placeholder="Datepicker"
           ngModel
           bsDatepicker
           [minDate]="minDate"
           [maxDate]="maxDate">
```

But I am not getting calendar in textbox.. Can anyone tell me what mistake I have done?

Answer (score 0):

```
dob: Date;
public maxDob: Date;
const year = this.dob.getFullYear() - 18;
const month = this.dob.getMonth();
const date = this.dob.getDate();
this.maxDob = new Date(year, month, date);

formInitialization(customerDetail ? : any) {
    dateOfBirth: [customerDetail ? customerDetail.dateOfBirth : ''],
}
```

```
  <div class="col s4">
   <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="common-form-field-width">
      <input readonly #dateFormat matInput 
      formControlName="dateOfBirth" [max]="maxDob" [matDatepicker]="picker" 
      placeholder="Date of Birth">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
   </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

[image]